# Is there any way to visualize Ring structure using Cayley digraph?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, visualization, ring-homomorphism, ring-isomorphism

In Nathan Carter's Visual group theory there is a nice description of how to explore group structure through Cayley digraph and how the structures reflect themselves in Cayley tables.For example subgroups,cosets,homomorphisms etc.

Now I am studying Ring theory,but I cannot find any similar reference that provides methods to visualize Rings and its structures like ideals,quotients and homomophism of rings.

Such visualization often helps us to construct nice counterexamples.Can someone suggest me some nice text that describes ring theory is a visual apporach using Cayley diagram in detail.I also want to know how Cayley tables (of addition and multiplication) reflect the structures.

Comment: In 15 years of studying rings, I've never run across this.  I haven't used Cayley tables for groups either.   I'm not sure how many people study the equivalent of "geometric group theory" for rings.